# UI freezes in Tkinter while I run something in background in a while loop

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I know this question has been asked a lot of times. Unfortunately, none of the answers resolve my purpose. I have a code which will continuously ping in a while loop and check the connectivity. The frequency in which the ping should be instantiated is got from the user. This ping will never end unless the user closes the application.

I have 2 classes, one for UI and another for the action to be done.

Below is the sample code.

```
class Net:

     def main(self,interval):

        try:
           while thread1.is_alive():
                 p = subprocess.Popen("Do something like ping",
                                      stdout = PIPE, 
                                      stderr = PIPE)  #--> This is definitely required

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                 print "Exiting", e



class UI:

     def __init__(self,* args, **kwargs):        

         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

         self.wm_title("Network Test")
         self.geometry('250x75')
         self.resizable(width = False, height = False)

         self.label = tk.Label(text = "Frequency(seconds)")
         self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

         self.entry = tk.Entry(bd = 5)
         self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

         self.button = tk.Button(text = "Start Test", command = self.callthread)

         self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

         self.button1 = tk.Button(text = "Stop Test")
         self.button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

         self.mainloop()

   def callthread(self):

       print "Inside Call thread"

       n = NetTest()
       thread2 = threading.Thread(target = n.main(int(self.entry.get())))
       #thread2.setDaemon(True)
       thread2.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target = MyUI)

    thread1.start()
    #print threading.activeCount()
```

I tried running them in threads but in vain.Perhaps I have implemented the thread wrongly. The application does what it is supposed to do. The only problem is the UI hangs while it does.I have also tried using after. That didnt help as well.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem.The problem was, I had not called the main method from the run method(). This example might be helpful for people trying to implement thread with Tkinter so that the UI does not freeze.

The best solution was to inherit the threading module and call the infinite loop from the overridden run method as given below.

```
class Net(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, interval):
     threading.Thread.__init__(self)
     self.interval = interval

   def run(self):

     self.main()

   def main(self,interval):

       try:
         while thread1.is_alive():
             p = subprocess.Popen("Do something like ping",
                                  stdout = PIPE, 
                                  stderr = PIPE)  #--> This is definitely required

       except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
             print "Exiting", e



class UI:

   def __init__(self,* args, **kwargs):        

     tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

     self.wm_title("Network Test")
     self.geometry('250x75')
     self.resizable(width = False, height = False)

     self.label = tk.Label(text = "Frequency(seconds)")
     self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

     self.entry = tk.Entry(bd = 5)
     self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

     self.button = tk.Button(text = "Start Test", command = self.callthread)

     self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

     self.button1 = tk.Button(text = "Stop Test")
     self.button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

     self.mainloop()

   def callthread(self):

       thread2 = Net(self.entry.get())
       thread2.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target = MyUI)
    thread1.start()
```